# Prevent resize or overlapping of certain elements in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want the event in white to be background event and the blue events to overlap on those white events. Can anyone help? It should show the white as background and the blue events on top of white but the size of white should not be compromised while the blue events are being stacked on top of the  white event**(as in the picture the white is being overlapped whie the blue events are being added)**.

[image: events overlapping]

Comment: use z-index to order div. you have to edit the plugin. add a custom class to that div and update the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `rendering` property, from the docs:

```
Allows alternate rendering of the event, like background events.
Can be empty, "background", or "inverse-background"
```

Set `rendering` for the white event to `'background'` and it will be behind all the other events.

Docs: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: I tried in the fiddle, it does work, but since im using V 1.6, its not working in my app atm. will upgrade it to latest version available and try it. Appreciate your feedback.